# Convert strings of values with = to a single dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a python file that contains these elements:

```
startaddress    = 768
length      = 64
subChId     = 6
protection  = 1
bitrate     = 64
```

and I want to convert them to a single dictionary string like this:

```
{"startaddress":"768","length":"64","subChId":"6","protection":"1","bitrate":"64"}
```

so I can read the values individually using json.loads().

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned code

```
import csv
output = {}
with open("a.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='=')
    for row in reader:
        output[row[0].strip()] = row[1].strip()
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have all these variables stored in a file called `data.py`

```py
import json
import data

variables = [var for var in dir(data) if not var.startswith('__')]
dictionary = {var:getattr(data,var) for var in variables}

json = json.dumps(dictionary)
```

Hope this helps.